# Typoscript override based on layout

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

How can I use multiple overrides based on the layout?

Single use currently works like this:

```
tt_content.image.20.1 {
  file.width.override {
    override = 200c
    override.if {
      equals.field = layout
      value = 1
    }
  }
}
```

But I need a different width override for different layout values.

I think I need to do something like this incorrect code:

```
#does not work    
tt_content.image.20.1.file.width = CASE
tt_content.image.20.1.file.width {
    key.field = layout
    1 = TEXT
    1.value = 200c
    2 = TEXT
    2.value = 400c
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if an attribute must be enhanced you (nearly) always can use `.cObject` to enhance it [1].
so you might use something like this:

```
tt_content.image.20.1 {
  file.width.override {
    override.cObject = CASE
    override.cObject {
      key.field = layout
      1 = TEXT
      1.value = 200c
      2 = TEXT
      2.value = 400c
    }
  }
}
```

[1] this belongs to typoscript used by the core. extensions like plugins, userfuncs may handle their typoscript on their own way not conform to core functionality like `.stdWrap`